# ASP.NET redirect from event handler hot by button clicked by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, postback

I have a problem with a page not redirecting during a postback.

I have an aspx-page with this content being part of it:

```
<td class="tdinput" align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonFrigiv" runat="server" Text="Frigiv sag" CssClass="button"
        OnClientClick="verifyReleaseOtherEmployeesCase()" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonFrigivHidden" OnClick="ButtonFrigiv_Click" 
        Style="display: none;" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
</td>
```

The page also contains various UpdatePanels, however the above code is not included in one.
As it is seen there's a button being displayed, which calls the following JavaScript:

```
function verifyReleaseOtherEmployeesCase() {
    var logonUser = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenLogonUser.ClientID %>');
    var lockedBy = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenLockedBy.ClientID %>');

    var button = document.getElementById('<%= ButtonFrigivHidden.ClientID %>');

    if (logonUser.value == lockedBy.value) {
        button.click();
    }
    else if (confirm("Danish confirm message")) {
        button.click();
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

So basically this JavaScript locates the 2nd button above (which is not being displayed to the user) and clicks it.
When the button is clicked the following event handler is reached on the server:

```
protected void ButtonFrigiv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NyeSagerDAC.FrigivSag(SagID, LogonUser);
    Response.Redirect(LastList);
}
```

Where LastList is a string containing the page which was the entry point for the current page (there are multiple entry points).
The server method is reached and the first line in the method is executed perfectly, however the page is not redirected.
I have done some testing regarding whether it might have been considered an AJAX-callback (which doesn't allow redirects) using the following code in the event handler:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
string header = request.Headers["X-MicrosoftAjax"];
```

The content of the string header is empty and the Page_Load is called after the event handler is done. So I don't think this is the problem.

I have also tried to register a startup script to have the page redirect itself instead. This has been tried in various ways:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"redirect",
    "window.location.href='" + LastList + "'");
```

And

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect",
    "window.location.href='" + LastList + "';", true);
```

However none of this seems to work.
The only thing I have got to work was when I removed the confirm() part of the JavaScript and had it just click the button. This resulted in the page being correctly reloaded. However, I need to ask the user actually wants to unlock another employee's task.

So I think my question is: How can I get the page to redirect? Alternatively, how can I modify the JavaScript to still ask the user to confirm and not stopping the redirect from working?

The solution is coded in .NET 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js function is named verifyReleaseOtherEmployeesCase but in the OnClientClick it says verifyReleaseOtherWorkersCase, assuming that is a typo you also need to prevent the first button from performing a postback.

Notice the return of false in the js function and the return in the OnClientClick

```
function verifyReleaseOtherEmployeesCase() {
    var logonUser = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenLogonUser.ClientID %>');
    var lockedBy = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenLockedBy.ClientID %>');

    var button = document.getElementById('<%= ButtonFrigivHidden.ClientID %>');

    if (logonUser.value == lockedBy.value) {
        button.click();
    }
    else if (confirm("Danish confirm message")) {
        button.click();
    }

    return false;
}

 <asp:Button ID="ButtonFrigiv" runat="server" Text="Frigiv sag" CssClass="button"
    OnClientClick="return verifyReleaseOtherEmployeesCase()" />
```

Comment: It worked perfect. Thanks! Regarding the typo, it was not present in the actual code. Thanks for noticing, though. I just think I lack the proper JavaScript-knowledge to know why the function have to return false.